# Why does en IF statement make my function repeat?

Tags: javascript, shake

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="sv">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Sensor Assignment</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Demo av en animerad bil som kan manipuleras med mobiltelefoners gyro-sensor">
    <meta name="author" content="b22thohe">

    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/HGustavs/Shaker.js/master/shaker.js"></script>

    <script>
      var toggle = 0;

      function changeBackground(edata) {
        /* Debug output */
        document.getElementById("printout").innerHTML += "Detected SHAKES: " + edata.shakes + "<BR>"; /* print out # shakes registered */

        if (toggle == 0) {
          document.getElementById("svg").style.background = 'linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(150,150,150,1) 43%, rgba(0,187,255,1) 62%, rgba(0,63,255,1) 93%)'; // Ändrar bakgrunden i viewboxen
          document.getElementById("sun").transform.fill('yellow'); // Ändrar bakgrunden på solen   
          toggle = 1;
        } else if (toggle == 1) {
          document.getElementById("svg").style.background = 'linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(23,16,198,1) 7%, rgba(30,10,138,1) 39%, rgba(56,56,59,1) 100%)'; // Ändrar bakgrunden i viewboxen
          document.getElementById("sun").transform.fill('lightgrey'); // Ändrar bakgrunden på solen
          toggle = 0;
        }
      };

      function initShake() {
        shaker.on("shake", function(edata) {
          changeBackground(edata);
        });
      }

    </script>

    <style>
      /* Skapar en gradient som bakgrund och centrerar elementet */
      svg {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(150, 150, 150, 1) 43%, rgba(0, 187, 255, 1) 62%, rgba(0, 63, 255, 1) 93%);
      }

      /* flyttar ut alla SVG-objekt till startposition */
      #grp-body {
        transform: translate(275px, 235px);
      }

      #grp-cockpit {
        transform: translate(237.5px, 210px);
      }

      #grp-back-tire {
        transform: translate(187.5px, 260px);
      }

      #grp-front-tire {
        transform: translate(362.5px, 260px);
      }

      #grp-back-hubcap {
        transform: translate(187.5px, 260px);
      }

      #grp-front-hubcap {
        transform: translate(362.5px, 260px);
      }

      #grp-back-wing {
        transform: translate(137.5px, 197.5px);
      }

      #grp-front-wing {
        transform: translate(418.75px, 203.75px);
      }

      #grp-smoke {
        transform: translate(75px, 205px);
        transition: opacity 9s;
      }

      #grp-exhaust {
        transform: translate(112.5px, 247.5px)
      }

      #grp-exhaust-flame {
        transform: translate(86px, 246px);
      }


      /* Animerar rökpuffen */
      @keyframes smoke {
        0% {
          transform: translate(75px, 205px) scale(1);
          opacity: 1;
        }

        33.3% {
          transform: translate(3px, 93px) scale(0.3);
          opacity: 0;
        }

        66.6% {
          transform: translate(-69px, -19px) scale(0.2);
        }

        75% {
          transform: translate(-107.5px, -82.5px) scale(0.1);
        }

        100% {
          transform: translate(-146px, -146px) scale(0);
        }
      }

      #grp-smoke {
        animation-name: smoke;
        animation-duration: 12000ms;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-play-state: paused;
        opacity: 0;
      }

      /* Animerar bilens rörelse */
      @keyframes drive {
        0% {
          transform: translateX(-460px);
        }

        100% {
          transform: translateX(1260px);
        }
      }

      #grp-entire-vehicle {
        animation-name: drive;
        animation-duration: 9000ms;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-play-state: paused;
      }

    </style>

  </head>

  <body id="content" onload="initShake();">
    <!-- Skapar en rityta -->
    <svg id="svg" width="100%" viewbox="0 0 900 300" style="border:1px solid black;">

      <defs>
        <!-- Skapar gradient för däcken -->
        <radialGradient id="tire-gradient">
          <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#6f6e6e" />
          <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#000000" />
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#6f6e6e" />
        </radialGradient>

        <!-- Förbereder animerad bild för bakgrund till navkapslarna -->
        <pattern id="hubcap-img" x="0" y="0" height="15" width="15">
          <image x="0" y="0" width="15" height="15" xlink:href="./img/hubcap.png"></image>
          <animateTransform id="hubcapAnim" attributeType="xml" attributeName="patternTransform" type="rotate" from="0" to="360" begin="0" dur="9s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        </pattern>
      </defs>

      <!-- Ritar ut bilkroppen -->
      <g id="grp-entire-vehicle">
        <!-- FÖRARHYTT -->
        <g id="grp-cockpit">
          <path id="cockpit" d="M 0 0 A 25 18.75 0 0 1 100 0" fill="lightblue" stroke="blue" stroke-width="1" stroke-miterlimit="5" />
        </g>
        <!-- DÄCK -->
        <g id="grp-back-tire">
          <circle id="back-tire" stroke-miterlimit="5" cx="0" cy="0" r="15" fill="url(#tire-gradient)" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        </g>
        <g id="grp-front-tire">
          <circle id="front-tire" stroke-miterlimit="5" cx="0" cy="0" r="15" fill="url(#tire-gradient)" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        </g>
        <!-- NAVKAPSLAR -->
        <g id="grp-back-hubcap">
          <circle id="back-hubcap" stroke-miterlimit="5" cx="0" cy="0" r="7.5" fill="url(#hubcap-img)" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        </g>
        <g id="grp-front-hubcap">
          <circle id="front-hubcap" stroke-miterlimit="5" cx="0" cy="0" r="7.5" fill="url(#hubcap-img)" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        </g>
        <!-- KAROSS -->
        <g id="grp-body">
          <rect id="main-body" x="-150" y="-25" width="300" height="50" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" fill="lightblue"></rect>
        </g>
        <!-- KAROSS-VINGAR -->
        <g id="grp-back-wing">
          <polygon id="back-wing" stroke-miterlimit="5" points="-12.5,12.5 12.5,12.5 -12.5,-12.5 -12.5,12.5" fill="lightblue" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"></polygon>
        </g>
        <g id="grp-front-wing">
          <polygon id="front-wing" stroke-miterlimit="5" points="6.25,6.25 -6.25,6.25 6.25,-6.25 6.25,6.25" fill="lightblue" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"></polygon>
        </g>
        <!-- RÖKPUFF -->
        <g id="grp-smoke">
          <circle cx="9.162" cy="8.185" r="25" fill="rgb(79,77,76,1)" />
          <circle cx="-5.838" cy="3.185" r="25" fill="rgb(79,77,76,1)" />
          <circle cx="-15.838" cy="11.815" r="21" fill="rgb(79,77,76,1)" />
        </g>
        <!-- AVGASRÖR -->
        <g id="grp-exhaust">
          <polygon id="exhaust" stroke-miterlimit="5" points="-12.5,-9.375 -12.5,9.375 -3.125,6.25 3.125,3.125 12.5,3.125 12.5,-3.125 3.125,-3.125 -3.125,-6.25 -12.5,-9.375" fill="lightgray" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5"></polygon>
        </g>
        <!-- AVGAS-FLAMMOR -->
        <g id="grp-exhaust-flame">
          <polygon id="exhaust-flame" stroke-miterlimit="5" points="-25,-23.4375 -12.5,-17.25 -3.125,-11 6.25,-4.75 12.5,-4.75 12.5,7.75 6.25,7.75 -3.125,14 -9.375,20.25 -15.625,23.375 -12.5,17.125 -6.25,7.75 -12.5,10.875 -18.75,14 -31.25,17.125 -25,7.75 -12.5,-1.625 -25,-7.875 -37.5,-14.125 -31.25,-17.25 -12.5,-7.875 -18.75,-17.25 -25,-23.5" fill="yellow" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"></polygon>
        </g>
      </g>

      <!-- SOL -->
      <g id="sun">
        <circle cx="500" cy="50" r="50" fill="yellow" />
      </g>
      <!-- Start-knapp -->
      <g id="grp-start-button" onClick="startAnimation()">
        <a href="#">
          <rect x="30" y="30" width="100" height="50" stroke="black" fill="green" stroke-width="3" />
          <text x="53" y="63" font-family="helvetica neue" font-size="25" fill="yellow">Start</text>
        </a>
      </g>
      <g id="grp-stop-button" onClick="stopAnimation()">
        <!-- Stopp-knapp -->
        <a href="#">
          <rect x="140" y="30" width="100" height="50" stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="3" />
          <text x="163" y="63" font-family="helvetica neue" font-size="25" fill="yellow">Stop</text>
        </a>
      </g>
    </svg>

    <pre id="printout">Shaker Events Printout<br></pre>

  </body>

</html>
```

I've been banging my head against a wall for awhile now so I'm not even sure what I'm doing anymore. The basis is this: I'm using a javascript library to identify when the user "shakes" the phone.

The initShake() function is called on body load. From there I call changeBackground function that outputs the number of shakes registered. This all works fine until I put an IF/ELSE IF statement inside the changeBackground statement, because then the number of shakes output starts repeating seemingly infinitely. And I can't wrap my head around why?

I would like to know why this happens, and of course good ways to remedy this. Is it because of faulty IF statements or something else? Is it because of faulty IF statements or something else?

This is my HTML with the body onload call and element for outputting number of shakes:

```
<body id="content" onload="initShake();">
   <pre id="printout">Shaker Events Printout<br></pre>
</body>
```

This is the initShake() function:

```
function initShake() {
    shaker.on("shake",function(edata){
        changeBackground(edata);
    });
}
```

And this is the changeBackground function:

```
function changeBackground(edata) {
    /* Debug output */
    document.getElementById("printout").innerHTML+="Detected SHAKES: "+edata.shakes+"<BR>"; /* print out # shakes registered */
};
```

And here's where I load the shaker script:

```
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/HGustavs/Shaker.js/master/shaker.js"></script>
```

This is the IF/ELSE IF statement that I put inside the changeBackground function:

```
if (toggle == 0) {
    document.getElementById("svg").style.background = 'linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(150,150,150,1) 43%, rgba(0,187,255,1) 62%, rgba(0,63,255,1) 93%)'; // Ändrar bakgrunden i viewboxen
    document.getElementById("sun").transform.fill('yellow'); // Ändrar bakgrunden på solen   
    toggle = 1;
} else if (toggle == 1) {
    document.getElementById("svg").style.background = 'linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(23,16,198,1) 7%, rgba(30,10,138,1) 39%, rgba(56,56,59,1) 100%)'; // Ändrar bakgrunden i viewboxen
    document.getElementById("sun").transform.fill('lightgrey'); // Ändrar bakgrunden på solen
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the code that doesn't work? The `if/else` code?

Comment: I wanted to know first if there was something wrong with the code I presented that would make this behaviour when insert an IF statement. But I have updated the original question now.

Comment: Shouldn't you have `toggle = 0` in the second `if` block?

Comment: @Akmal `initShake()` is not an event handler, and there's no default action for the "shake" event anyway.

Comment: Yes, I know the IF statement is all wrong. But does that really xplain the behaviour?

Comment: Show the actual code so it can be run.

Comment: Is `toggle` used or set anywhere else?

Comment: @pointy Can you explain this a bit more? I know that it works without the IF statements, but not with them...

Comment: I'll see if I can set up a basic jsfiddle for this. I just concluded there's something wrong with my code - not having anything to do with the library...

Comment: @ThomasHelsing did you see Barmar's comment? When `toggle == 1` the code does not set it back to 0. Is that intentional?

Comment: To be clear, simply adding an `if` statement does not affect anything **unless** the code involved in the `if` statement is broken.

Comment: @Pointy My fault, I didn't think a bad IF statement could cause this particular problem.

Comment: Updated with the entire code in a Jsfiddle now.

Comment: Please add the code as stack snippet to your question, not a link to an external website.

Comment: @jabaa Sorry, still learning. Done now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this works exactly, but could you try changing:

```
document.getElementById("sun").transform.fill('yellow');
```

to

```
document.getElementById("sun").querySelector("circle").style.fill = 'yellow';
```

(and do the same for the lightgrey version).

For anyone who wants to try this in the browser here's a hacky bit of code to do the shaking:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let event = new DeviceMotionEvent('devicemotion', {accelerationIncludingGravity:{ x: 50 * (i % 2 === 0 ? -1 : 1), y: 0, z: 0 }});

      window.dispatchEvent(event);
    }, i * 100 + (i % 2 === 0 ? 50 : 0));
}
```

Comment: Wow, I have actually been needing some pseudo shaking code. That is extremeley helpful.
Other than that, I realized I had the wrong code for changing color on my svg images, but I changed it to

document.getElementById("sun").style.fill = 'yellow';

Which made it work. But your solution is good as well. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasHelsing Yeah the shaking code took the most time; I think it was mainly from looking through shaker.js, looking stuff up on MDN (e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceMotionEvent ) and a fair bit of trial and error.